# How does CXF Bus and STSClient deal with SSL Certificate and Proxy?

Tags: cxf

I'm using **CXF** 3.1.5, How can I apply **proxy** settings and trust or ignore **SSL certificate** when sending out request?

I use **CXF** in the following two ways.

1. Using **org.apache.cxf.bus** to get WSDL definition from IdP or SP,  `bus.getExtension(WSDLManager.class).getDefinition()`.
2. Using **org.apache.cxf.ws.security.trust.STSClient** to request Security Token.`stsClient.requestSecurityToken()`

and I think I need to use code for configuration instead of configuration file as my callers send me those information about proxy and SSL certificates.

thanks a lot!

After further research, I found something.
to resolve the first problem, add the following code:
            `ResourceManager extension = bus.getExtension(ResourceManager.class);
            extension.addResourceResolver(new ResourceResolver() {
                @Override
                public <T> T resolve(String resourceName, Class<T> resourceType) {
                    return null;
                }
                @Override
                public InputStream getAsStream(String name) {
                    if (!name.startsWith("https")) {
                        return null;
                    }
                    org.apache.http.client.HttpClient httpClient = HttpUtils.createHttpClient(setting);
                    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(name);
                    try {
                        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                        return httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        return null;
                    }
                }
            });`

then I can get the WSDL definition, but I still don't know how to fix the second problem, I'm trying to use `HTTPConduit`(`(HTTPConduit)stsClient.getClient().getConduit()`), but when call `stsClient.getClient()`, cxf will try to load those XML Schema which will lead to the following exception:


`org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: Failed to create service.
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceFactory.create(WSDLServiceFactory.java:170)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.trust.AbstractSTSClient.createClient(AbstractSTSClient.java:657)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.trust.AbstractSTSClient.getClient(AbstractSTSClient.java:480)
    ...
Caused by: org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaException: Unable to locate imported document at 'https://...&xsd=ws-trust-1.3.xsd', relative to 'https://...#types1'.
    at org.apache.cxf.catalog.CatalogXmlSchemaURIResolver.resolveEntity(CatalogXmlSchemaURIResolver.java:76)
    at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.SchemaBuilder.resolveXmlSchema(SchemaBuilder.java:684)
    at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.SchemaBuilder.handleImport(SchemaBuilder.java:538)
    at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.SchemaBuilder.handleSchemaElementChild(SchemaBuilder.java:1516)
    at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.SchemaBuilder.handleXmlSchemaElement(SchemaBuilder.java:659)
    at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaCollection.read(XmlSchemaCollection.java:551)
    at org.apache.cxf.common.xmlschema.SchemaCollection.read(SchemaCollection.java:129)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.SchemaUtil.extractSchema(SchemaUtil.java:140)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.SchemaUtil.getSchemas(SchemaUtil.java:73)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.SchemaUtil.getSchemas(SchemaUtil.java:65)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.SchemaUtil.getSchemas(SchemaUtil.java:60)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceBuilder.getSchemas(WSDLServiceBuilder.java:378)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceBuilder.buildServices(WSDLServiceBuilder.java:345)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceBuilder.buildServices(WSDLServiceBuilder.java:209)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceFactory.create(WSDLServiceFactory.java:162)
    ... 32 more`

Comment: If there's a problem with a certificate, usually a "Handshake error" is thrown. Are you sure the ws-trust schema is there / available? (if the WSDL has been retrieved, I'd assume the SSL connection is working)

Comment: the ws-trust schema is available, it throws Handshake error if I remove the ResourceResolver. `javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException: faultCode=PARSER_ERROR: Problem parsing 'https://...?wsdl'.: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`

Comment: It seems like CXF will use ResourceResolver to load the resource, and it succeeded, then use URIResolver(CatalogXmlSchemaURIResolver) to resolve it again, at that time, it failed and thrown the exception described in my question.

Comment: I have a question - why do you use the resolver? If the resource is available as the HTTP resource, wound't be easier to put the server's certificate to the trsutstore?

Comment: I'm working on a SDK, my callers decide whether it should trust server's certificate or ignore it. beside that, there is still a proxy problem. so I need to deal with it dynamically. fortunately, I found a solution, please check my answer, I'll appreciate your opinions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution:
implements HTTPConduitFactory and put it into bus.
`bus.setExtension(new MyHTTPConduitFactory(setting), HTTPConduitFactory.class)`

In the Factory class:
`@Override
    public HTTPConduit createConduit(HTTPTransportFactory f, Bus b, EndpointInfo localInfo,
            EndpointReferenceType target) throws IOException {
        return new MyHTTPConduit(settings, f, b, localInfo, target);
    }`

MyHTTPConduit extends URLConnectionHTTPConduit
To handle SSL certificates.

```
    TLSClientParameters parameters = new TLSClientParameters();

    parameters.setDisableCNCheck(settings.isTurnOffHostVerifier());

    if (settings.isIgnoreServerCertificate()) {
        parameters.setTrustManagers(new TrustManager[] { new TrustAllCertsTrustManager() });
    } else {
        TrustManagerFactory factory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        factory.init(settings.getTrustStore());
        parameters.setTrustManagers(factory.getTrustManagers());
    }

    this.setTlsClientParameters(parameters);
```

TrustAllCertsTrustManager class

```
private class TrustAllCertsTrustManager implements X509TrustManager {

    @Override
    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1) throws CertificateException {

    }

    @Override
    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1) throws CertificateException {

    }

    @Override
    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
        return null;
    }

}
```

To handle proxy.

```
        HTTPClientPolicy httpClientPolicy = new HTTPClientPolicy();
        httpClientPolicy.setProxyServer(proxy.getHostName());
        httpClientPolicy.setProxyServerPort(proxy.getPort());

        this.setClient(httpClientPolicy);
```

Comment: Nice :) You've effective built an HTTP condiut trusting all server certificates. For basic approach it looks ok, for security purposes I'd prefer placing the server's certificate into a trustore (you can configure in the TLSClientParameters) to trust the server specifically. It is a very common approach to have an application truststore.

Answer (score 0):

There are some examples here: http://cxf.apache.org/docs/client-http-transport-including-ssl-support.html

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, however it doesn't fit me well, I edited my question after some research, please take a look.